# Сделать заглавной каждую букву каждого слова, начинающегося с заглавной буквы

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Есть некоторая строка. Сделать заглавной каждую букву каждого слова, начинающегося с заглавной буквы. Понимаю, что необходимо разбить строку на массив. Но как написать if который будет искать слово с заглавной буквы

```
public string capSentences(string str)
{
    string[] array = str.Split(' ');
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не используй foreach, используй for.
Вот код, который вы хотели:

```
string yourLine = "пайтон? Я тебя найду и Заставлю учить C#";
string[] words = yourLine.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i += 1)
  if (char.IsUpper(words[i][0]))
     words[i] = words[i].ToUpper();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", words));
```

Вероятно, Regex будет самым оптимизированным, но честно, я до сих пор в нём не разбираюсь

Comment: yourLine - топовый пример

Answer (score 3):

Можно с помощью [`s[0].IsUpper()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-char-isupper-method/?ref=lbp), где `s` — строка из массива:

```
foreach (string s in array) {
    if (s[0].IsUpper()) {
        // дальше выводим слово в заглавном регистре
    }
}
```